# Node's IP exposed

Tags: go-ethereum, security, nodes, network

I've run an Ethereum full node using Geth. I want to know if my public IP is exposed? Could hackers target my machine through the Internet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yes your node will be exposed to the public you could check it in https://www.ethernodes.org/network/1/nodes you will find your public IP.

hackers indeed could target your machine (Dos) and scan its ports to search for any any vulnerability. Use a VPN or TOR to hide your real IP and configure your firewall to permit only the ports that Geth uses.

Comment: Tor won't work as it's TCP-based, whereas Ethereum also requires UDP (for peer discovery). A VPN or proxy is the best bet.

Comment: @RichardHorrocks yes for peer discovery but ONLY for peer discovery. If you manually add a few nodes, you can use Ethereum over TOR, transactions can be relayed. Took me a while to understand the distinction and even though it is 5 years later I want to help make this better understood.