# Is it possible to tell which node broadcast a transaction?

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes, node-discovery

If I host my own node and send my transactions through this node, can somebody see that my address sends transactions through my pseudo-anonymous node?

If yes, can someone set up a watcher that tracks all transactions through this node?

If no, can you spin up two node (one physical close to and one physically far away from the node in question), and estimate where the node is based on when these two nodes receive a transaction? This would be similar to pinging a website from one side of the country vs the other to check latency and determine where the servers are.

Edit:

In [this](https://youtu.be/3P4fVCmTbtI?t=840) presentation (at ~14:00), the speaker talks about the GeoIP information as well as "cycling their eNodes for privacy...I don't want somebody to be detecting where tx are originating from" (at 15:30). This makes me think that the answer above is yes.

Looking at [this](https://www.ethernodes.org/node/002197c1271ab789548ce78d5f9be3c08100c9fa189c533a2ed14caf01d8ce9d6d691bddf13105b3958f339852b1b2da28d76b18dc2123be7b70bb837bb78852) site, it appears that you can actually get a location (based of IP, I assume).

Comment: Edited my answer after your edit. Enode address can't give you account information as nodes and accounts are not related - accounts just utilize some node. A valid question would be "what is the username part in an enode" so I just posted a question about it: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/66858/what-is-the-username-node-id-in-an-enode-url

Comment: Great. Gave you credit in my edit as well.

Comment: Dude, you can't edit your post to say it was edited due to my edit because I edited my post due to your edit! :)

Comment: Lol unedited! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that with "address" you mean IP address? IP addresses are exposed when running a node ([Node's IP exposed](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9498/nodes-ip-exposed)). You can of course get some information based on an IP (geolocation for example) but that information is not directly related to the Ethereum network.

Even if your node's IP is known, it doesn't give any attacker much information. The only thing they know is that there exists a node with the given IP. It is not possible in any direct or simple way to know which node actually sends which transaction. Upon some googling I stumbled upon this interesting article which attempts to (in theory) find out which node is the originator of which transaction: https://media.consensys.net/exploring-pseudonimity-on-ethereum-dda257019eb4

So, no, it's not possible to know which node sends which transactions (without such difficult & inaccurate statistical methods). Yes, you know your peers' enode addresses but those are not related to the accounts which use the node - nodes and accounts are not linked.

As for your last question, I believe the linked article gives you an answer. (Yes, in theory, to some degree, but in practice probably no).

Comment: I'm trying to look to content secure by allow-list c̶o̶n̶s̶e̶n̶s̶u̶s̶ hullabaloo with node Ethereum records [778](https://ethereum-magicians.org/t/nonce-minter-bot-for-erc20mintable-open-source-wallet-supply-recovery). I've found the RLPReader library, and [an implementation](https://www.mdpi.com/1999-5903/12/8/134), but not how to get this base64 binary from [any global variable](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.5.3/miscellaneous.html?highlight=tx.origin#global-variables) yet.